# Ant script to run sql scripts on linux system

Tags: windows, linux, ant

My database is on linux system. I have sql scripts that i need to run on that database. I need to write an ant script that should run from a windows system and run the sql scripts. How should i do that?

Answer (score 2):

You will use the `<sql>` tag. See [the documentation](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/sql.html). There are some good examples there, such as:

```
<sql
    driver="org.database.jdbcDriver"
    url="jdbc:database-url"
    userid="sa"
    password="pass"
    >
insert
into table some_table
values(1,2,3,4);

truncate table some_other_table;
</sql>
```

You will need to have the JDBC driver in your classpath. I'd put it in explicitly in the `<classpath>` subelement. (There's an example for that, too).

Edit: For Oracle, the JDBC driver will be something like `ojdbc.jar`. The driver will probably be `oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver` and the URL probably match the pattern `jdbc:oracle:thin:@//[HOST][:PORT]/SERVICE`. See the [Oracle JDBC FAQ](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/JDBC) for examples and more detail. If you don't have any luck with this approach then you have a driver, network or authentication issue. Please post the exact error you receive.

Comment: this is for windows system. My db is on linux server.

Comment: @avdroidDev.  What makes you think this will not work on linux?

Comment: @avdroidDev.  What is the error that you get, if any?  Please edit your question with this info.  If it is something like `connection timeout`, then it is a different problem

Comment: If you have a command that does what you want in bash, then use the `exec` task to call out to it. But @Raghuram is right, this should work on linux also. What is your db?

Comment: db is oracle. i think "<sql>" will work on linux system, when the ant script runs on linux system. But my ant script needs to run on windows and then remotely connct to linux system and run the scripts.